# Owl carousel auto play without delay

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
          $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            items:5,
            center:true,
            autoplay:true,
            autoPlayTimeout:1000,
            autoplaySpeed:3000,
            autoHeight:true,
            autoplayHoverPause:false,
            loop:true,
            // smartSpeed:1000,
            margin:5,
            responsive:{
                480:{
                  items:3,
                  margin:2
                },
                919:{
                    items:4,
                    margin:4
                }
            }
          });
      });
```

```css
.main-content {
  position: relative;
}
.main-content .owl-theme .custom-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.main-content .owl-theme .custom-nav .owl-prev, .main-content .owl-theme .custom-nav .owl-next {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  color: inherit;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  z-index: 100;
}
.main-content .owl-theme .custom-nav .owl-prev i, .main-content .owl-theme .custom-nav .owl-next i {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #cecece;
}
.main-content .owl-theme .custom-nav .owl-prev {
  left: 0;
}
.main-content .owl-theme .custom-nav .owl-next {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Owl Carousel 2 Navigation on Sides - Left and Right</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

<style>
.owl-carousel,.owl-carousel .owl-item
{-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
position:relative}

.owl-carousel
{display:none;
width:100%;
z-index:1}

.owl-carousel .owl-stage
{position:relative;
-ms-touch-action:pan-Y;
touch-action:manipulation;
-moz-backface-visibility:hidden}

.owl-carousel .owl-stage:after
{content:".";
display:block;
clear:both;
visibility:hidden;
line-height:0;
height:0}

.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer
{position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}

.owl-carousel .owl-item,.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper
{-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
-moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
-ms-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}

.owl-carousel .owl-item
{min-height:1px;
float:left;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
-webkit-touch-callout:none}


.owl-carousel .owl-item img
{display:block;
width:100%}

.owl-carousel .owl-dots.disabled,.owl-carousel .owl-nav.disabled
{display:none}

.no-js .owl-carousel,.owl-carousel.owl-loaded
{display:block}

.owl-carousel .owl-dot,.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next,.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev
{cursor:pointer;
-webkit-user-select:none;
-khtml-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
user-select:none}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-next,.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-prev,.owl-carousel button.owl-dot
{background:0 0;
color:inherit;
border:none;
padding:0!important;
font:inherit}

.owl-carousel.owl-loading
{opacity:0;
display:block}

.owl-carousel.owl-hidden
{opacity:0}

.owl-carousel.owl-refresh .owl-item
{visibility:hidden}

.owl-carousel.owl-drag .owl-item
{-ms-touch-action:pan-y;
touch-action:pan-y;
-webkit-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
user-select:none}

.owl-carousel.owl-grab
{cursor:move;
cursor:grab}

.owl-carousel.owl-rtl
{direction:rtl}

.owl-carousel.owl-rtl .owl-item
{float:right}

.owl-carousel .animated
{animation-duration:1s;
animation-fill-mode:both}

.owl-carousel .owl-animated-in
{z-index:0}

.owl-carousel .owl-animated-out
{z-index:1}

.owl-carousel .fadeOut
{animation-name:fadeOut}

@keyframes fadeOut{0%{opacity:1}100%{opacity:0}}

.owl-height{transition:height .5s ease-in-out}

.owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy
{opacity:0;
transition:opacity .4s ease}

.owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy:not([src]),.owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy[src^=""]{max-height:0}

.owl-carousel .owl-item img.owl-lazy
{transform-style:preserve-3d}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-wrapper
{position:relative;
height:100%;
background:#000}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-play-icon
{position:absolute;
height:80px;
width:80px;
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin-left:-40px;
margin-top:-40px;
background:url(owl.video.play.png) no-repeat;
cursor:pointer;
z-index:1;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
transition:transform .1s ease}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-play-icon:hover
{-ms-transform:scale(1.3,1.3);
transform:scale(1.3,1.3)}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-playing .owl-video-play-icon,.owl-carousel .owl-video-playing .owl-video-tn
{display:none}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-tn
{opacity:0;
height:100%;
background-position:center center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
transition:opacity .4s ease}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-frame
{position:relative;
z-index:1;
height:100%;
width:100%}

</style>


</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
   <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img class="img-clients" src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/6.jpg" alt="" ></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-clients" src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/6.jpg" alt="" ></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-clients" src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/6.jpg" alt="" ></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-clients" src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/6.jpg" alt="" ></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-clients" src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/6.jpg" alt="" ></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-clients" src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/6.jpg" alt="" ></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-clients" src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/6.jpg" alt="" ></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-clients" src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/6.jpg" alt="" ></div>
    </div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js'></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
          $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            items:5,
            center:true,
            autoplay:true,
            autoPlayTimeout:1000,
            autoplaySpeed:3000,
            autoHeight:true,
            autoplayHoverPause:false,
            loop:true,
            // smartSpeed:1000,
            margin:5,
            responsive:{
                480:{
                  items:3
                },
                919:{
                    items:4
                }
            }
          });
      });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

as you can see this owl carousel has a delay.
I think there doesn't have animation-delay code
but it moves after a few second delay

where should I fix it?
or what should I add to this code?
to make it play without any delay.

if there isn't have any way to remove this delay then can you advise me
how to make delay time to be short?

Comment: If you want to work it like https://codepen.io/mdrezwanferdous/pen/wpNZxN   then just use the custom owl-carousel they have used. the way owlCarousel library works with a timeout I do not think you can remove that that initial timeout, unless you edit the library and change according to your need, which exactly what the other url that you gave are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code. First time it will change slide after 6 seconds.

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items:5,
        center:true,
        autoplay:true,
        autoPlayTimeout:100,
        autoplaySpeed:6000,
        autoHeight:true,
        autoplayHoverPause:false,
        loop:true,
        // smartSpeed:1000,
        margin:5,
        responsive:{
            480:{
              items:3
            },
            919:{
                items:4
            }
        }
      });
```

Comment: Hi! really appreciate for your help but can we change this like this? codepen.io/mdrezwanferdous/pen/wpNZxN (that is exactly what i want- playing without delay)

Comment: You need to add autoplayTimeout to 500.

Answer (score 1):

You should try:
autoPlayTimeout:0
or
autoplaySpeed:0

Comment: Hi! firstly thanks for your help :D but it is not work :( it still have delay ;;

Answer (score 1):

you need to adjust `autoPlayTimeout` and `autoplaySpeed`

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items:5,
      center:true,
      autoplay:true,
      autoPlayTimeout:500,
      autoplaySpeed:5500,
      autoHeight:true,
      autoplayHoverPause:false,
      loop:true,
      // smartSpeed:1000,
      margin:5,
      responsive:{
          480:{
            items:3
          },
          919:{
              items:4
          }
      }
  });
});
```

```css
.main-content {
  position: relative;
}
.main-content .owl-theme .custom-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.main-content .owl-theme .custom-nav .owl-prev, .main-content .owl-theme .custom-nav .owl-next {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  color: inherit;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  z-index: 100;
}
.main-content .owl-theme .custom-nav .owl-prev i, .main-content .owl-theme .custom-nav .owl-next i {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #cecece;
}
.main-content .owl-theme .custom-nav .owl-prev {
  left: 0;
}
.main-content .owl-theme .custom-nav .owl-next {
  right: 0;
}

.owl-carousel,.owl-carousel .owl-item {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
  position:relative;
}

.owl-carousel {
  display:none;
  width:100%;
  z-index:1;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
  position:relative;
  -ms-touch-action:pan-Y;
  touch-action:manipulation;
  -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-stage:after {
  content:".";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
  visibility:hidden;
  line-height:0;
  height:0;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item,.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper {
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
  -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
  -ms-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item {
  min-height:1px;
  float:left;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-touch-callout:none;
}


.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-dots.disabled,.owl-carousel .owl-nav.disabled {
  display:none;
}

.no-js .owl-carousel,.owl-carousel.owl-loaded {
  display:block;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-dot,.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next,.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev {
  cursor:pointer;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  -khtml-user-select:none;
  -moz-user-select:none;
  -ms-user-select:none;
  user-select:none;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-next,.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-prev,.owl-carousel button.owl-dot {
  background:0 0;
  color:inherit;
  border:none;
  padding:0!important;
  font:inherit;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-loading {
  opacity:0;
  display:block;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-hidden {
o pacity:0;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-refresh .owl-item {
visibility:hidden;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-drag .owl-item {
  -ms-touch-action:pan-y;
  touch-action:pan-y;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  -moz-user-select:none;
  -ms-user-select:none;
  user-select:none;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-grab {
  cursor:move;
  cursor:grab;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-rtl {
  direction:rtl;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-rtl .owl-item {
  float:right;
}

.owl-carousel .animated {
  animation-duration:1s;
  animation-fill-mode:both;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-animated-in {
  z-index:0;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-animated-out {
  z-index:1;
}

.owl-carousel .fadeOut {
  animation-name:fadeOut;
}

@keyframes fadeOut{0%{opacity:1}100%{opacity:0}}

.owl-height {
  transition:height .5s ease-in-out;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy {
  opacity:0;
  transition:opacity .4s ease;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy:not([src]),.owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy[src^=""] {
  max-height:0;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item img.owl-lazy {
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-wrapper {
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  background:#000;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-play-icon {
  position:absolute;
  height:80px;
  width:80px;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin-left:-40px;
  margin-top:-40px;
  background:url(owl.video.play.png) no-repeat;
  cursor:pointer;
  z-index:1;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  transition:transform .1s ease;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-play-icon:hover {
  -ms-transform:scale(1.3,1.3);
  transform:scale(1.3,1.3); 
}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-playing .owl-video-play-icon,.owl-carousel .owl-video-playing .owl-video-tn 
  display:none;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-tn {
  opacity:0;
  height:100%;
  background-position:center center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  transition:opacity .4s ease;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-frame {
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js'></script>

<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-clients" src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/6.jpg" alt="" >
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-clients" src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/6.jpg" alt="" >    
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-clients" src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/6.jpg" alt="" >
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-clients" src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/6.jpg" alt="" >
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-clients" src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/6.jpg" alt="" >
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-clients" src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/6.jpg" alt="" >
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-clients" src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/6.jpg" alt="" >
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-clients" src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/6.jpg" alt="" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! really appreciate for your help but can we change this like this? https://codepen.io/mdrezwanferdous/pen/wpNZxN (that is exactly what i want- playing without delay)